# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same even after put model and input to cuda

Tags: pytorch

I met "RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same" even after I put my input and model to device. I would be appreciated if someone could help me out.

```
point_net.to(device)
for epoch in range(100):
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0.0
    total = 0
    
    for i in range(0, points_tensor.shape[0], 2048):
        X = points_tensor[i:i + 2048]
        y = labels_tensor[i:i + 2048]
        
        X = X.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        y_pred = point_net(X)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
```

Comment: is your model on the GPU ?

Comment: This is weird indeed. You should put the whole stacktrace here as well. Also print the `device`. It may be 'cpu' while the model is called `cuda` somewhere else

Comment: Please show the full code and error message

Comment: Thanks for everybody's reply. Very appreciated. Actually I found the error and it is due to an intermediate output in my model which is not put to cuda.